# edit sampleID info in vcf file

Tags: linux, sed, error-handling, edit, vcf-vcard

I have a vcf file whose header has sample ID info.
It looks like this:

> ##fileformat=VCFv4.2
> ##FILTER=<ID=PASS,Description="All filters passed">
> ##fileDate=20220214
> ##source=PLINKv1.90
> ##contig=<ID=1,length=249212497>
> ##INFO=<ID=PR,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="Provisional reference allele, may not be based on real reference genome">
> ##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
> #CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  GTEX-1117F_GTEX-1117F   GTEX-111CU_GTEX-111CU   GTEX-111FC_GTEX-111FC
> GTEX-111VG_GTEX-111VG   GTEX-111YS_GTEX-111YS   GTEX-1122O_GTEX-1122O
> GTEX-1128S_GTEX-1128S   GTEX-113IC_GTEX-113IC   GTEX-113JC_GTEX-113JC
> GTEX-117XS_GTEX-117XS

I want to edit it to contain only

> ##fileformat=VCFv4.2
> ##FILTER=<ID=PASS,Description="All filters passed">
> ##fileDate=20220214
> ##source=PLINKv1.90
> ##contig=<ID=1,length=249212497>
> ##INFO=<ID=PR,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="Provisional reference allele, may not be based on real reference genome">
> ##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
> #CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  GTEX-1117F   GTEX-111CU  GTEX-111FC   GTEX-111VG  GTEX-111YS
> GTEX-1122O  GTEX-1128S GTEX-113IC   GTEX-113JC   GTEX-117XS

Basically I want to remove anything coming after _
For example:
ID:GTEX-1117F_GTEX-1117F
desired ID: GTEX-1117F

I used this command but its not really giving me the desired output.

```
sed -e '$s/\[[[:digit:]]\+\]//g; s/_GTEX[[:digit:]]\+//g'chr1_impute_qc.vcf > chr1_impute_qc1.vcf
```

Can anyone help me with this one?

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\(GTEX-[[:alnum:]]*\)_\1/\1/g' file
ID:GTEX-1117F
```